# How to get ngx-chips value in ngModel?

Tags: angular7, ngx-chips

I have implemented ngx-chips in an email address field. It works well. But, when I output the value in component.ts, I get only the first chip's value. How to get the value of all the chips?

If I have a@xyz.com and b@xyz.com in the html, only a@xyz.com comes in the ngModel.

**component.html**

```
<div class="form-row">
    <div class="required form-group col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" >
      <label class="control-label" for="email.emailCc">CC:</label>
       <tag-input [ngModel]="[email.emailCc]"  theme='bootstrap'>
        <tag-input-dropdown [autocompleteObservable]="items" [showDropdownIfEmpty]="true" [dynamicUpdate]="false"></tag-input-dropdown>
        </tag-input>
    </div>
 </div>

 <div class="form-group col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
     <button (click)="sendEmail()" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block">Send</button>
 </div>
```

**component.ts**

```
 public items = (text: string): Observable<Response> => {
   return this.sendEmailService.getEmailList(text);
 };

sendEmail(){
   console.log("email cc:"+this.email.emailCc);
 }
```

**Output**

```
email cc:a@xyz.com
```

Comment: RiyaGeorge, how you solved your problem? I have the same requirement as yours.